# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have an ASP.NET website that uses the ReportViewer control. I'm using SQL server 2008 from reporting. The reporting services are on another machine on the local network and my asp.net web site is on my local system. This has been working fine for the same machine like when I access reports on network it works

```
http:\\exampledomainname\reportsserver
```

But when I want to access my reports from local host,
i.e http:\localhost\reports
I get the following error :

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

Any other assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the impersonation for you web service in your web.config. This user must have permissions on the reporting server:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Comment: Please refer these links [Link1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/2d216af4-6586-4619-b8aa-56f05cbd8239/)[Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/984954.aspx/1) Same is helpfull for mine case.